# Autodesk Forge - (RVT Model) Forge to three.JS to .USDZ

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to convert assemblies from a .RVT model to three.JS to .USDZ for AR. I have a list of assemblies and want to process each individual file into the final format of USDZ for AR. Does anyone have any good recommendations? I’m thinking Model Derivative IFC to three.JS to .USDZ but would love know the best method for this! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `ModelDerivative` API allows you to convert your `RVT` file (and many others) into `SVF` (or `SVF2`) to be used by the `viewer` for example. Then you can use [Forge Convert Utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forge-convert-utils) package to extract the geometry and create a `glTF` of your model.

`glTF` is widely used for AR but if you need to use `USDZ`, you can easily convert your model with this kind of tool : [USD_From_glTF](https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf)